# MSSQL: calculate time be many starts and stops

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to make this in sql:

Have table with records:

```
    ID      LaborID     OrderNr      OrderStatusID  OrderStatusDate


    12990   3731573     OPT1814378          2       2018-05-28 09:35:30.123
    13105   230687389   OPT1814378          1       2018-05-29 10:32:14.850
    13106   230687389   OPT1814378          2       2018-05-29 10:52:14.403
    13123   230480202   OPT1814378          1       2018-05-29 13:18:05.233
    13130   230480202   OPT1814378          0       2018-05-29 13:29:17.360
    12837   3731573     OPT1814089          2       2018-05-25 20:28:24.817
    12906   10138504    OPT1814089          1       2018-05-26 10:41:18.680
    12909   10138504    OPT1814089          2       2018-05-26 10:57:40.733
    12913   10138504    OPT1814089          1       2018-05-26 11:41:48.387
    12920   10138504    OPT1814089          0       2018-05-26 12:15:48.590
```

where

```
OrderStatusID   
0 - End
1 - Begin
2 - pause
```

Need calculate working time `from begin to pause` `(1->2)`  or `from begin to end` `(1->0)`. 
My problem is that there are some conditions that I have to adhere to:

If first record is `2` then ignore

Work begin always with `1`

But can have more pause `(1->2)`
The last work end record everytime with `0`

The result in this case will be:

```
OPT1814378          230687389   00:20:00      
OPT1814378          230480202   00:11:12   
OPT1814089          10138504    00:16:12
OPT1814089          10138504    00:34:00
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but it probably happened because you showed zero effort towards solving your problem.  This actually looks like it will need an ugly query, all the more reason to try something before posting.

Comment: i am very happy, that you see it as an ugly query, because I think about it two days how can i do that... and in my first sentence i ask if is possible. I am not sql profi..sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this is not that ugly.

```
; with 
cte as
(
    -- CTE for generating a sequence no
    select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by OrderNr 
                                           order by OrderStatusDate)
    from    @table
),
cte2 as
(
    -- Clean up invalid any rows and regenerate new sequence no
    select  ID, LaborID, OrderNr, OrderStatusID, OrderStatusDate, 
            rn = row_number() over (partition by OrderNr 
                                        order by OrderStatusDate)
    from    cte
    where   (rn = 1 and OrderStatusID = 1)
    or      rn  >= 2
)
select  OrderNr, LaborID,
        convert(varchar(10), 
                dateadd(second, 
                        datediff(second, 
                                 min(OrderStatusDate),
                                 max(OrderStatusDate)), 
                        0), 
                108)
from    cte2
group by OrderNr, 
         LaborID, 
         (rn - 1) / 2
```

`(rn - 1) / 2` will gives the value 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 etc for grouping the rows two by two.

Answer (score 0):

This one also works

```
;WITH CTE
AS ( 
    SELECT row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY ordernr ORDER BY id ) RN ,* FROM test_ti 
    )

,cte2
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte c1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM cte c2
            WHERE c1.id = c2.id
                AND c2.rn = 1
                AND c2.orderstatusid = 2
            )
    )
SELECT OrderNr
    ,LaborId
    ,TimeInterval
FROM ( SELECT DateDiff(MI, TIME, NxtTm) TimeInterval ,*
    FROM (
        SELECT * ,lead(TIME) OVER ( ORDER BY id ) NxtTm
        FROM cte2
        ) x
    WHERE orderstatusid <> 0
    ) y
WHERE orderstatusid = 1
```